# jpa lazyloading fails in production mode - in testmode it works fine

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I call a Service to load a entity. If I run this in a integrationtest it is all fine, but in real life on the server it fails.

Some of the properties in this entity are collections. The entity has bean loaded in both cases. When I stop the execution in debugmode with a breakpoint in the near of "query.getSingleResult()" I see, that the collections loaded. But only in a testrun...

I stop the same code in a servletcontainer and get a InvocationException!?

My environment look´s like:
spring 3.1
hibernate 3.6.6.Final

Things i have tried:
- search for differences in context.xml (test and production)
- use the other context.xml file (test) in productionmode

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.hoeso.gwt.platform.server.domain.common.Person.anschrift, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:248)
    at de.hoeso.sis.server.services.common.impl.UserServiceBeanImpl.login(UserServiceBeanImpl.java:397)
    at de.hoeso.sis.server.rpc.LoginService.execute(LoginService.java:35)`

I find out, that in testmode the hibernate session is connected and open. In productionmode (in servletcontainer there is no connected hibernatesession available via `entitymanager.getDelegate()`.

Comment: Is your test method loads children in transaction?

Comment: "and get a InvocationException" Adding a copy of the stack-trace for the `InvocationException` might help people wanting to answer your question. What are the differences between your test and production bean configurations?

Comment: @JMelnik: It is the same transaction. I load the entity and the next line of code get this error.

Comment: @Raedwald: There are no differences between the two configurations. As I sayd: I have allready tried to use the testContext.xml in production - and it fails too.

Comment: Well contexts are different? In test context it works, and in servlet it does not?

Comment: @JMelnik Yes, i use different context.xml files. But if I substitute the one with the other there are no changes in the result. Test works, production not.

Comment: There is no session in the servlet context..?

Comment: @JMelnik You mean a hibernate session? The hibernate session object (wrapped by the entitimanager) is not conntected...

Comment: I think that it is just that there are no transaction in code you are executing. Please provide method/class where you are accessing collection.

Comment: Thats it! I forgot a @Transactional annotation in the type hierarchie of the servicebean class. Thx to JMelnik!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the solution of my own problem with a little help from JMelnik. For the posterity I will share my solution...

After I put a breakpoint in close to the code to which I load the object, I saw the main differences.

```
return entitymanager.isOpen();
```

(boolean) true    // testmode and productionmode

```
return ((org.hibernate.Session)entitymanager.getDelegate()).isConnected();
```

(boolean) true  // in testmode
(boolean) false // in productionmode

```
return ((org.hibernate.Session)entitymanager.getDelegate()).isOpen();
```

(boolean) true   // in testmode
(boolean) false  // in productionmode

```
return((org.hibernate.Session)entitymanager.getDelegate()).getTransaction().isActive();
```

in productionmode this throws a Exception
in testmode this returns: (boolean) true

Conclusion: The code is running in production mode without a transaction. In test mode, a transaction is present, because the test class inherits from a superclass, which is annotated with @Transactional. In the hierarchy of ServiceBean I had forgotten this.

The annotation is inserted and it all works perfectly!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~